# (Higher) flat connections and Grothendieck construction

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, connections

For any (nice) topological space there is an equivalence between covering spaces and local systems $\pi_1X \to \operatorname{Set}$. We can think of it as a Grothendieck construction. If we take instead the entire homotopy type $\Pi_{\leq \infty}X \to \infty\operatorname{Grpd}$ we get the theory of Grothendieck construction for higher categories (or "straightening-unstraightening"). In case $X$ is a smooth manifold, we have the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence $$\left\{ \Pi_{\leq1}X\to\operatorname{Vec}_{k}\right\} \simeq \operatorname{Flat}\left(X\right)$$between local systems with values in vector spaces and flat connections. If we take the entire homotopy type $\Pi_{\leq \infty}X \to \mathcal{D}\left(k\right)$ there is a [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870813004118) by Block and Smith that describes the corresponding $\infty$-category of flat connections.

My question is: Is there a theory of Grothendieck construction for maps $\Pi_{\leq 1}X \to \operatorname{Vec}_k$, $\Pi_{\leq \infty}X \to \mathcal{D}\left(k\right)$ (or more generally $\Pi_{\leq \infty}X \to \operatorname{Sp}$) for a general $X$, that descent to the above theory of flat connection in case $X$ has the homotopy type of a smooth manifold?

Comment: This could be relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.07941